# Can't draw related model data, get invalid foreach argument

Tags: php, yii2

Attempting to recast a Yii 1.1 application in Yii2 advanced template, and stumbling on the display of related model data in a view.

Have searched for answers regarding this but as far as I can tell, I'm following Yii2 protocols for gathering the data, and other extended examples I've seen have all been related to e.g. GridView

Relevant Model code:

frontend/config/main.php

```
return [
...
'components' => [
...
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules'=> [
            'home' => 'page/home',
                '<alias:about>' => 'page/page',
                'page/<alias>' => 'page/page'
            ],
],
```

common/models/Page.php

```
namespace common\models;
use Yii;
/**
 * This is the model class for table "page".
...
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property Content[] $contents
 */

class Page extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'page';
    }

...
    public function getContents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Content::className(), ['pageId' => 'id']);
    }
...
```

models/common/Content.php

```
namespace common\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "content".
...
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property Page $page
 */
class Content extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'content';
    }

...

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'slug', 'pageId', 'content'], 'required'],
            [['pageId'], 'integer'],
            [['content'], 'string'],
            [['name', 'slug'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['pageId'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Page::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['pageId' => 'id']],
        ];
    }
...
    public function getPage()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Page::className(), ['id' => 'pageId']);
    }
```

frontend/controllers/PageController.php

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function actionPage($alias)
    {
        $model=$this->loadContent($alias);
    if ($alias == "home")
    {
       $news=$this->loadRecentNews();
    }
    $this->render('default',[
        'model'=>$model,
        'news'=>$news
    ]);
    }

...

    public function loadContent($page)
    {
    $pageModel = Page::find()->where(['slug'=>$page])->with('contents')->all();
    if($pageModel===null)
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested Page could not be found.');
    return $pageModel;
    }

    public function loadRecentNews()
    {
    $newsModel = News::find()->orderBy('create_time DESC')->limit(2)->all();
    return $newsModel;
    }
```

frontend/views/page/default.php (portion that fails)

```
<?php foreach ($model->contents as $content) { ?>
    <h3><?php echo $content->name; ?></h3>
    <?php echo $content->content; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: First of all `$model` is an array , your `loadContent` function is querying all not one.

Comment: Argh.  It didn't even occur to me that the AR would find only one result but still return it as an array.

I'm now getting a blank screen but it's already better than the error screen so I'll try to suss out the rest on my own.